# How can I tell which app is producing debug statements in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I'm trying to figure out what is producing this debug output:

04-25 15:58:04.883 1542-5012/? D/NetworkStatsCollection: getHistory:mUID 10266 isVideoCallUID: false

The above output runs continuously with my phone plugged in. I don't see this using the emulator and I've uninstalled the app I'm working on, so I don't think it's that. I've tried restarting the phone, to no avail. How can I determine what app is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `adb shell ps | fgrep 1511` to see what app is tied to the PID of 1511, which according to your LogCat output is the app that is doing the logging.

(BTW, in the future, please post LogCat output as text, not screenshots)

Comment: I was able to get an output using "adb shell ps", but the fgrep command failed - "not recognized..." Anyway, this answers the question as I was able to scroll through the results to find PID of 1542 (it changed after I reconnected the phone, apparently.) Thanks.

Comment: @Sux2Lose: Sorry, I didn't think that through. `fgrep` is usually pre-installed on Linux and (I think) macOS.

Comment: np. This is the resulting row from the output causing all the trouble. Any insight? or should I open another question?
system    1542  895   2798344 254712 SyS_epoll_ 0000000000 S system_server

Comment: Well, `system_server` is one of the core OS processes. If I had to guess, your device manufacturer tinkered around with something and left that debugging line in.

Comment: This started happening on my device as well, see my comments here for suggestions:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622349/923920